# Find four elements in a random array whose sum equals a given target

Tags: c#, algorithm

Say the array is :`60,45,30,45,45,5,60,45,30,30,45,60,60,45,30,30,60,30,30`.
I need to find the numbers in the array whose sum is equal to 180, I do not need multiple possibilities, only one correct choice is good.
As you can see the values in data set might repeat.
But the whole operation should be very efficient as the data set might vary (more samples).

Comment: What is **specific** problem here?

Comment: Went through different sorting techniques, wondering if it might be useful.

Comment: Have to tried to solve this problem as a paper exercise before starting to code? I.e. have you thought about how you might solve this?

Comment: `Went through different sorting techniques` which one? Why those techniques where bad?

Comment: Vote for reopen .... this is obviously a real question, and is quite well specified. The OP didn't make much of an attempt to solve it, which may be a reason to downvote it but not to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Sort the numbers. Iterate through the values (skipping duplicates) that are less than the sum, subtracting each in turn from the sum and recursively solving for the reduced sum, starting from the next value after the one last selected. (This gives you the numbers in increasing order.) You can speed up the last (fourth) level (when you're looking for an exact value) by doing a binary search instead of a linear one.

For example, after the sort:

```
5,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,60,60,60,60,60
    try 5 and solve for 175:
        try 30 and solve for 145:
            try 30 and solve for 115: fail
            try 45 and solve for 100: fail 
            try 60 and solve for 85: fail
        try 45 and solve for 135:
            try 45 and solve for 95: fail
            try 60 and solve for 75: fail
        try 60 and solve for 115:
            try 60 and solve for 55: fail
    try 30 and solve for 150:
        try 30 and solve for 120:
            try 30 and solve for 90: fail
            try 45 and solve for 75: fail
            try 60 and solve for 60: success {30,30,60,60}
```

(If you want to find all the solutions, then don't stop on success and you'll quickly find {30,45,45,60} as well.)

Comment: @SteveJessop Skipping duplicates during the *search*, not as elements of the sum. That is, you don't have to try both {60<1>, 60<2>,...} and {60<2>,60<1>,...} ... ah, but that means the recursion can start from the previous point ... gotta fix the answer.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, yes. Don't bother "recursing" more than once on the same chosen value, but leave the dupes available for the next choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
var someEnumerable = new int[] { 60,45,30,45,45,5,60,45,30,30,45,60,60,45,30,30,60,30,30 };
var target = 200;
var solutions = from a1 in someenumerable
                from a2 in someenumerable
                from a3 in someenumerable
                from a4 in someenumerable
                let sum = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4
                where sum == target
                select new { a1, a2, a3, a4 };

var firstSolution = solutions.First();

Console.WriteLine("Possible solution: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", firstSolution.a1, firstSolution.a2, firstSolution.a3, firstSolution.a4);
```

Comment: obviously I missed a where :)

Comment: This will use same element up to four times. I think this is not allowed. If you run this for "20" you will get "5, 5, 5, 5" as a solution.

Comment: And surely this solution only works where 4 (and only 4) numbers in the set aggregate to the target value?

Comment: @YiğitYener, you are right, my proposition allows a unique item to be used several times. This is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @tomfanning The question title starts "Find four elements..." so I read this the same way as Steve.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. (Was it edited in?) Carry on!

Comment: Y'know, I actually provided a correct *and* efficient (that was a requirement) solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easier variant of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

The fact that you want *exactly* 4 elements added together, rather than a subset of any size, means that obviously it can be done in polynomial time.

It *appears* from your example that all values in the array are non-negative, which makes it considerably easier to do either with dynamic programming or an explicit branch-and-bound (which probably amounts to more or less the same work as a DP approach, not necessarily done in the same order)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like knapsack problem to me with an extra condition(maximum weight ==(instead of <=) your magic number). Can give it a thought.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but the solution may consist of more than four numbers:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        Calculate(180, 0, 0, array, indexes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(array[indexes[i]].ToString() + " [" + indexes[i].ToString() + "], ");
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }

    bool Calculate(int goal, int sum, int index, int[] arr, List<int> indexes)
    {
        if (index > arr.Length - 1)
            return false;
        sum += arr[index];

        if (sum == goal)
        {
            indexes.Add(index);
            return true;
        }
        else if (sum > goal)
            return false;
        else
        {
            bool result = false;
            int count = 0;
            while (!(result = Calculate(goal, sum, index + ++count, arr, indexes)) && (index + count) < arr.Length) ;
            if (result)
            {
                indexes.Add(index);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
```